# Pyinfra run python code inside target host

Tags: pyinfra

What would be the most appropriate way to execute arbitrary python code inside the target host ?

I saw the [operations.python](https://docs.pyinfra.com/en/latest/operations/python.html) which use *"the context of a deploy"*. The context seem to be an interface representing the host, but python code is running inside the master computer.

With the following snippet, it shows code is not executed on target, having working directory of the master :

```py
from pyinfra.operations import python
import os

def callback(state, host):
    print(os.getcwd())
    print(os.getuid())

python.call(name="Python callback",
        function=callback)
```

Should I put a script on the host and execute it, or there is a cleaner alternative ?

Comment: It depends if you actually want to run python code or not.  Based on your example, if you just want to get facts on a remote host, you run "facts" at command line or implement them in a separate file. 
 https://docs.pyinfra.com/en/latest/facts/server.html  What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: The idea is to execute python code inside the remote machine, code defined in the pyinfra script. Can I create, for example with this callback, something which manipulate a file directly in the remote host ?

Comment: You can use callbacks, but I would only use them as a last resort.  Common tasks like file manipulation might be easier with `files` operations https://docs.pyinfra.com/en/1.x/operations/files.html and `server` operations https://docs.pyinfra.com/en/1.x/operations/server.html.  Note: both work on remote hosts too.

Comment: "code is running inside the master computer" - sounds like you're using the `@local` connector  (e.g. `> pyinfra @local tasks/task.py`).  To deploy code against a remote host, you can set up an inventory file specifying host + connection info.  This lets you run something like a task/deploy file of operations from local to a remote, (e.g. `> pyinfra inventories/remotes.py tasks/task.py`).  The file structure is documented here: https://docs.pyinfra.com/en/1.x/deploys.html